# Vue 3 load component dynamically from string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Trying to dynamic load components based on a string.

Should look something like this:

```html
<component v-for="component in components" :is="eval(component)" />
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

The workaround I'm using for now is creating a function returning the component:

```html
<script setup>
import BarChart from '@/components/BarChart.vue'

const components = ['BarChart']

const stringToComponent = component => {
  return eval(component)
}
</script>

<template>
  <component v-for="component in components" :is="stringToComponent(component)" />
</template>
```

Why is calling eval directly not working and is it possible to avoid creating a function?

Answer (score 2):

Add the component to the array without defining as string `const components = [BarChart]` :

```html
<script setup>
import BarChart from '@/components/BarChart.vue'

const components = [BarChart]

</script>

<template>
  <component v-for="component in components" :is="component" />
</template>
```

Comment: :in was a typo. I'm using :is but it expects a component not a string.

Comment: @ErikAlserda please check my edited answer

Comment: My example is pseudo code, the array of components are fetched from a API so it will be a array of strings.

Comment: what about `import {h} from 'vue'` and use `h` instead of `eval`